# arrow function and this

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm browsing twitter and found this tweet:

https://twitter.com/_ericelliott/status/855598297939144704

Here is the code from the tweet:

```
const double = () => this.x * 2;
const numDouble = double.bind({ x: 5 });
numDouble();
```

When you run this snippet in console it'll produce NaN.
How?
Author is explicitly binding the value of x, but still it's showing NaN.

Author is also specifying that arrow function can't bind this. As i know that arrow function lexically bind the value of this form surrounding scope. Then why author is claiming so?

Please clarify my doubts and Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: http://2ality.com/2012/04/arrow-functions.html    x => x + this.y is mostly syntactic sugar for function (x) { return x + this.y }.bind(this)

Comment: @zloctb: There are several other differences hiding in that "mostly." They don't have a `prototype` property and associated object, they don't have their own `arguments` binding, they don't have their own `super` binding (where relevant)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to remember is:

- **Arrow functions *close over* `this`, exactly the way that functions close over variables.** *(In fact, it's the same mechanism.)* Whatever `this` is where the arrow function is created is what `this` will be during a call to that arrow function. It will never be anything else. Arrow functions ignore the `this` they're called with.

If you remember that, you'll never be confused by `this` in an arrow function again.

> When you run this snippet in console it'll produce NaN. How? Author is explicitly binding the value of x, but still it's showing NaN.

`numDouble = double.bind({ x: 5 })` creates a new function (`numDouble`) that, when called, will call the original function (`double`) with `this` set to the value you provide as `bind`'s first argument (`{ x: 5 }`). But since arrow functions ignore the `this` they're called with, `bind` can't control what `this` they use.

> Author is also specifying that arrow function can't bind this. As i know that arrow function lexically bind the value of this form surrounding scope.

Right, which means you can't change it. Lexical binding is the way closures work. This arrow function:

```
const a = () => {
    console.log(typeof this);
};
```

treats `this` exactly the way this traditional function treats `thisWhereFunctionWasCreated`:

```
const thisWhereFunctionWasCreated = this;
const t = function() {
    console.log(typeof thisWhereFunctionWasCreated);
};
```

Just like you can't change what `thisWhereFunctionWasCreated` variable `t` uses when you call it, you can't change what `this` `a` uses when you call it. (If `thisWhereFunctionWasCreated` weren't a `const`, you *could* change the *value* it holds, but not *which `thisWhereFunctionWasCreated` variable* `t` uses. But it's a constant in that example because `this` is a constant.)

Since an arrow function completely ignores the `this` it was called with, it doesn't matter what mechanism you use to try to tell the arrow function what `this` to use, it won't work. Whether you specify `this` implicitly by calling the function as a method (`obj.arrow()`), or via `call` or `apply` (`arrow.call(obj)`), or via `bind` (`const boundArrow = arrow.bind(obj); boundArrow();`), it will still use the `this` it closes over instead:

```js
"use strict";

function Ctor() {
    
    // `this` will be the object created by `new Ctor`; grab it
    this.name = "outerThis";
    const outerThis = this;
    
    // `traditional` doesn't close over `this`, so you CAN change
    // what `this` it uses when you call it, in various ways
    function traditional(testNum) {
        console.log(testNum, "traditional:", getName(this));
    }
    
    // `arrow` closes over `this`, so you CAN'T change
    // what `this` it uses when you call it
    const arrow = testNum => {
        console.log(testNum, "arrow:      ", getName(this));
    };

    // Remember that the `this` in a direct call is the global
    // object in loose mode, `undefined` in strict mode; this
    // code is in strict mode
    console.log("Direct call (default `this`):");
    traditional(1);              // 1 traditional: window
    arrow(1);                    // 1 arrow:       outerThis
    
    console.log("`obj.xyz()`:");
    const obj = {
        name: "obj",
        arrow,
        traditional
    };
    obj.traditional(2);          // 2 traditional: obj
    obj.arrow(2);                // 2 arrow:       outerThis

    console.log("Using `call`:");
    traditional.call(obj, 3);    // 3 traditional: obj
    arrow.call(obj, 3);          // 3 arrow:       outerThis

    console.log("Using `bind` and calling result:");
    const boundTraditional = traditional.bind(obj);
    const boundArrow = arrow.bind(obj);
    boundTraditional(4);         // 4 traditional: obj
    boundArrow(4);               // 4 arrow:       outerThis
}

function getName(t) {
    switch (t) {
        case undefined:
            return "undefined";
        case window:
            return "window";
        default:
            return t.name;
    }
}

new Ctor();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

The only thing `bind` can do when called on an arrow function is bind arguments to it:

```js
const arrow = (x, y) => x + y;
console.log(arrow(2, 3));      // 5

const arrowWith2 = arrow.bind(null, 2);
console.log(arrowWith2(3));    // 5

const arrowWith2And3 = arrow.bind(null, 2, 3);
console.log(arrowWith2And3()); // 5
```

(It also sets the name of the resulting function to `"bound x"` [where `x` is the name of the original function. So `arrowWith2.name` in the above is `"bound arrow"`.)

Answer (score 5):

[**Arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) don't bind `this`. As per MDN:

> #### No binding of this
>
> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own `this` value
>   (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode
>   function calls, the context object if the function is called as an
>   "object method", etc.). This proved to be annoying with an
>   object-oriented style of programming.

So `this` in your example will be the global object `window` which apparently don't have a property called `x`.

**Example:**

```js
function foo() {
  let arrow = () => {
    console.log(this);     // will use foo's this as arrow will never have its own this
  }
  
  arrow.call({"x": "x"});  // ... even if we specify it using bind, call, or apply
}

foo.call({"y": "y"});      // specifying the this for foo (this value will eventually be used by arrow because it will be availbale in its scope)
```

Comment: Can you clarify it a bit more?

Comment: So according to MDN, arrow function don't bind this and also they don't have their own this.

Comment: @KishanPatel Arrow function are like shallow ones. They don't have their own `this` (even with `bind` they won't). They just use whatever `this` available by the scope they're in. I'll post an example.

Comment: Oh..that's why 'this' falls back to global object in our case. And 'this' is undefined on global window and that's it's showing NaN if you try to multiply this with 2.
Thanks for clarifying my doubts.

Comment: @KishanPatel Exactly! _And 'this' is undefined_ I think you meant _And 'x' is undefined_. Check the example above!