# Can't read data- attribute with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm generating Bootstrap pagination element with PHP within a loop.

```
<button class="page-link" data-page="'.$page_number.'">'.$page_number.'</button>
```

The element is generated correctly:

```
<button class="page-link" data-page="1">1</button>
```

Then in my script, I need to get this data-page to pass in forward.

I'm trying to do this:

```
$('#taskcontainer').on("click", $(".page-link"), () => {
       console.log($(this).data("page"));  
    })
```

But click on those buttons just gives me

```
undefined
```

I'm binding to #taskcontainer since this pagination elements are generated by PHP.

Comment: Change jQuery as `$('#taskcontainer').on("click", ".page-link", () => {
       console.log($(this).data("page"));  
    })`

Comment: @Dharman - The more direct equivalent of `this` if you're not using `this` is `event.currentTarget` rather than `event.target`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. Your delegated handler code is incorrect, you want to pass a *selector*, not a jQuery object, as the second argument. (See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).)
2. You're using an arrow function. For `this` to get set by jQuery, you need a traditional function (more on that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558721/arrow-function-and-this)).

So:

```
$('#taskcontainer').on("click", ".page-link", function() {
// No $( and ) here ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^--- no arrow function here
   console.log($(this).data("page"));  
})
```

If you want to keep using an arrow function, you can't use `this`, but you can accept the event parameter and use its `currentTarget` property:

```
$('#taskcontainer').on("click", ".page-link", (event) => {
// No $( and ) here ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^--- event parameter
   console.log($(event.currentTarget).data("page"));
// --------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attr-does/45149219#45149219) about `data` vs. `attr`.