# JavaScript Object Question: get the property value of an object using the object name

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I would like to ask a question about javascript properties of an object.
In the code below I have a javascript object. I would like to use the property "testName" inside the function "testFunction". I find out that the "this.testName" doesn't work in javascript object but if I do something like "TestObject.testName", it works properly. So in general, is it wrong to get the values of properties like "TestObject.testName" inside of the objects' functions?

````
const TestObject= {
    testName:"testValue",
    testFunction: ()=>{
        var result = TestObject.testName+ "result"; 
        return result ;
    }
} ```
````

Comment: _"I find out that the "this.testName" doesn't work in javascript"_ - it works but in your code it doesn't because of the arrow function. Any function that is supposed to be called as a _method_ should be declared using a regular function: `testFunction: function() { ... }` or using shorthand method syntax; `testFunction() { ... }`

Comment: see the dupe about why `this` doesn't work, to answer the question as asked, yes, it is wrong (mostly). On a more general note, it's better to use classes rather than "objects with functions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in general, is it wrong to get the values of properties like "TestObject.testName" inside of the objects' functions?

Not for singleton objects like that one, no, it's perfectly fine (you've used `const`, so no one can reassign `TestObject` to be something else). That said, the *reason* it's not working is that you've used an arrow function, not a traditional function or a method. If you used a traditional function or a method, `this` would work just fine (but keep reading):

```js
// Traditional function
const TestObject1 = {
    testName:"testValue",
    testFunction: function() {
        var result = this.testName+ "result"; 
        return result ;
    }
};

console.log(TestObject1.testFunction());

// Method
const TestObject2 = {
    testName:"testValue",
    testFunction() {
        var result = this.testName+ "result"; 
        return result ;
    }
};

console.log(TestObject2.testFunction());
```

I said "it would work just fine," but that's only true if `this` is set to `TestObject` when calling `testFunction`. It's possible to call `testFunction` such that `this` won't be set correctly, see the answers to [*How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) for details about those situations and how to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

use `this.testName` instead of `TestObject.testName`

You can read more about `this` here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp

@edit

Sorry, I didn't noticed that you've used arrow function. Try to use a regular function instead. Arrow functions are chaning the way that `this` keyword works

```
const TestObject= {
    testName:"testValue",
    testFunction: function(){
        var result = this.testName+ "result"; 
        return result ;
    }
}
```

You can find more information about it here:
[Arrow Functions and This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this)

Comment: It would result in `undefinedresult` as OP already mentioned it. *"this.testName" doesn't work in javascript object*

Comment: I get an error => TypeError: Cannot read property 'testName' of undefined

Comment: testName's scope is limited to TestObject so accessing it directly via `this` will not work. You'll have to go through TestObject. There is no workaround. You can do it like `this.TestObject.testName` though.

Comment: OK. but without using arrow function it works ! I thought the arrow function is the same as the regular function...

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan - 1. It's not a matter of scope, and 2. `this.TestObject.testName` won't work.

Comment: @Dennis - No, not at all. Arrow functions have several differences from traditional functions and methods. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896230/arrow-vs-classic-method-in-es6-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558721/arrow-function-and-this) and (er) in Chapter 3 of my recent book (links in my profile). :-)