# Accessing Pinia Plugin Augmented Properties in a Setup Store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

The Pinia documentation mentions using plugins to augment stores by adding properties as follows:

```
pinia.use(({ store }) => {
  store.hello = 'world'
})
```

Then wherever you use the store, you can access `store.hello` as follows:

```
const myStore = useMyStore()
console.log(store.hello)
```

I believe you can also access the augmented property from inside an Options store with `this.hello`. But I see no way to access this from inside a setup store. For example:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useProductStore = defineStore('products', () => {
  function getProducts() {

    ???.hello // <<<---- How do I access the augmented property here?

  }

  return { getProducts }
})
```

Comment: What happens when you try `this.hello`?  It worked when I tried locally. Also reproduced in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-night-553pr8?file=/src/stores/productStore.js)

Comment: Ah yeah, that works for actions! Thank you, @yoduh! However, it doesn't seem to work inside a computed prop or in the body of the setup function, any way to make those work?

Comment: Here is an edited [codesnadbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-plugin-properties-lc9df5) that shows it doesn't work in a computed prop.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is to define a state variable with the exact name of `hello` and start using that:

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { computed, ref } from 'vue';

export const useProductStore = defineStore('exampleStore', () => {
  const hello = ref(''); // << will be filled with the plugin installation

  const comp = computed(() => {
    return hello.value;
  });

  function getProducts() {
    return hello.value;
  }

  return {getProducts, comp, hello};
});
```

Explanation:

> If you want to add new state properties to a store or properties that are meant to be used during hydration, you will have to add it in two places:

1. On the store so you can access it with store.myState
2. On store.$state so it can be used in devtools and, be serialized during SSR.

So, [you'd better attach variables to `store.$state`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html#Adding-new-state).
I have provided you with a live example.

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue;
const { createPinia, defineStore } = Pinia;

const useProductStore = defineStore('exampleStore', () => {
  const hello = ref(''); // <<-- will be the value passed through in plugin installation

  const comp = computed(() => {
    return hello.value;
  });

  function getProducts() {
    return hello.value;
  }

  return {getProducts, comp, hello};
});


const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const store = useProductStore();
    const comp = store.comp; 
    const prod = store.getProducts(); 
    
    return {
      comp,
      prod,
    }
  }
});

const pinia = createPinia();

pinia.use(({store}) => {
  store.$state.hello = 'World of lions'
  // store.hello = 'world of lions (avoid)';
});

app
  .use(pinia)
  .mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia"></script>
    
<div id="app">
 <p> <i> computed </i> Hello {{ comp }} </p>
 <p> <i> function </i> Hello {{ prod }} </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Arrow functions don't bind this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558721/arrow-function-and-this)

So, when you can't access `this` in arrow function you can initial it in an init function. Make a variable for yourself and access it from there. [playground code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-glbjpu-9u5dss?file=src%2FApp.vue)

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { computed } from 'vue';

export const useProductStore = defineStore('exampleStore', () => {
  
  let _this = undefined;
  function init() {
    _this = this;
  }

  const product = computed(() => {
    return _this.hello;
  });

  function getProducts() {
    return _this.hello;
  }

  return { init, getProducts, product };
});
```

And use it in your file like this:

```js
<script setup>
import { useProductStore } from './stores/productStore';

const store = useProductStore();
store.init();
const product = store.getProducts();
</script>
```