How to access custom properties for pinia stores inside a setup store?
Let's say I define some custom properties for Pinia stores:
declare module 'pinia' {
   export interface PiniaCustomProperties {
      readonly router: Router;
      set hello(value: string | Ref<string>)
      get hello(): string
   }
}

How can I access these custom properties within a setup store?
export const useFilterStore = defineStore('filter', () => {
     // how to access "hello" and "router" here?

     console.log(this.hello) // <--- this is undefined
     console.log(hello) // <--- hello is undefined

})


Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76724803/accessing-pinia-plugin-augmented-properties-in-a-setup-store/77272412#77272412

Does this answer your question? Accessing Pinia Plugin Augmented Properties in a Setup Store
